# How can I fix the Python Debugger error(crash) on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Whenever I try to start debugging Python, this bar on the picture does not appear and I only get the output of My code. How can I fix it?[This happens when I start debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcgMN.png)                 [This Bar is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNZAP.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem. It suddenly started to happen.

I could solve it copy pasting a config I have in another computer.
Try adding this configuration to your 'launch.json' file in vs code and use it for debugging:

```
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    }
```